# Not receiving event in controller when using Backbone Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection of grants displayed on a page. When I type in a box, it filters the list down.
The text input triggers an event on a marionette itemView, which calls the controller with the filtered down collection:

```
keywordFilter: function (ev) {
    var keyword = ev.currentTarget.value;
    var controller = sff.app.router.controller;
    var collection = sff.app.grantList;

    var filtered = collection.filterByKeyword(keyword);
    controller._showGrants(filtered, 1);
}
```

This works fine but the way I get a reference to controller and collection doesn't look too good and supposedly using events is better, so I tried this:

In itemView:

```
keywordFilter: function (ev) {
    var keyword = ev.currentTarget.value;
    this.trigger('grants:filter', keyword);
}
```

In controller:

```
var GrantController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.viewClass = options.viewClass;
        this.app = options.app;
        this.collection = options.collection;

        this.on("grants:filter", function(keyword) {
            console.log(keyword);
            var filtered = this.collection.filterByKeyword(keyword);
            this._showGrants(filtered, 1);
        });
    },
    ...more methods...
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't receiving the event. I also tried this.app.on() and this.viewClass.on(), and this.on("itemView:grants:filter) but it's still not working.

As mentioned below, the controller has no reference to the itemView or vice versa. I think perhaps I want to be doing app.vent.trigger('grants:filter') but how do I get a reference to app from the itemView?

I'm starting to really hate backbone and marionette, I'd actually rather have jquery spaghetti than this nonsense.

Comment: Well, you're triggering an event on your ItemView and listening to an event on your controller. That won't work indeed. I suppose you have a reference to your view in the controller somewhere, use that as target for the event listener. Also try to use the `listenTo` instead of `on` event binding. In your example in the controller you can do something like `this.listenTo(viewReference, 'grants:filter', function()});`

Comment: The problem is, the controller is associated with a different view, so I have no reference to it.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using `wreqr` to raise and receive events. See: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#messaging-systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get a reference to it. You can trigger the event on other object, Backbone for example, and listen to it in the controller.

```
keywordFilter: function (ev) {
    var keyword = ev.currentTarget.value;
    Backbone.trigger('grants:filter', keyword);
}


var GrantController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        Backbone.on("grants:filter", function(keyword) {

        });
     },
...more methods...
```

}